# Count number of lines in file and save result to new text file

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, tcsh

I want to count the number of lines in a file called "cat"

my script to run in CMD is

```
echo -e "Enter file name: \c" 
read filename 
wc -l $filename

which leads to result [24 cat] after running
```

this ^^^ basically only gives me the number of lines in a file. But I want to save the results into a **new text file** that prints :

```
There are 24 cat, in the folder cat
```

Does anyone know how to save the information which the script provided?

Thanks everyone !

Comment: It's unclear what shell you are using.  You have tagged your question with [tag:tcsh], but your own answer would not run in the `tcsh`.  It would also not run correctly in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer to this question :

```
echo -e "Enter file name: \c" 
read filename                   #saves variable
total=$(wc -l $filename)       #calculate total lines in the *CAT* file
echo There are $total           #prints There are *numberoflines*

echo $total > newfile           #writes the answer into a newly created file
```

Thanks everyone that commented, not sure why it was deletd

Comment: Your script has syntax errors (spaces are not allowed around `=` in assignments), and variable expansions should always be double-quoted (your script does not work on files with spaces in their names).  If you are using `bash`, its `read` command has a `-p` option that is used to provide a prompt to the user.  Why is your script reading from the user interactively? It would be easier to take the pathname of the file on the command line. Likewesi, the output could be written to standard output and then redirected to some user-defined filename on the command line.